# Concrete cure time before laying hot asphalt beside?

Tags: concrete, asphalt

Let's say I pour concrete sidewalks (6" thick, 4' x 8'), how many days should I wait to have hot asphalt laid right beside it (it would butt to the short side - 4') ?

Was thinking of pouring the concrete on Tuesday, removing the forms on Wednesday, and have the asphalt laid on Thursday. Would this work ?

I am in Montreal, Canada. Forecasted temps are max 20C during daytime, 8C at night for the period in question (next week ;).

Thanks in advance for all advice you could bring me.

Answer (score 1):

Concrete institute recommends not removing forms 2-3 days after a pour.

Concrete will reach 50% to 60% of it’s final strength in 7 days.

I’d wait 7 days so there’s no (minimal) deforming of the concrete edge.